# git clone copying some files from other projects?

Tags: macos, git, rvmrc

I've forked a repository, and after doing so, attempted to clone it

```
$ git clone https://github.com/dax/newly_cloned_project.git
```

the clone is successful:

```
Cloning into '[newly_cloned_project]'...
remote: Counting objects: 180, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (143/143), done.
remote: Total 180 (delta 57), reused 144 (delta 21)
Receiving objects: 100% (180/180), 206.54 KiB | 268 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (57/57), done.
```

but when change directories to `newly_cloned_project`, i'm greeted with this:

```
You are using '.rvmrc', it requires trusting, it is slower and it is not compatible with other ruby managers,
you can switch to '.ruby-version' using 'rvm rvmrc to [.]ruby-version'
or ignore this warning with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /Users/charliekim/programming/developer application tasks/connect_four/.rvmrc',
'.rvmrc' will continue to be the default project file in RVM 1 and RVM 2,
to ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore all.rvmrcs'.
```

I'm using an `.rvmrc` file for other projects - but this is newly created and has no such file - upon closer inspection, it turns out that a fair few files are in my `newly_cloned_project` directory - including an `.rspec` file and accompanying `spec` directory...

I've looked around SO and Google but haven't seen any reference to this - I've triple checked my cloning process, so it's no problem there (that I can tell?) really not sure what's going on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake - if anyone else is having trouble like this, be sure to check that you've not made unnecessary changes to your user level `gitconfig` file (found at `~/.gitconfig` on unix systems).

I had added a remote for a specific repository in this file and that was causing the issue.

`~/.gitconfig`

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = [email_address]:dax/other_repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

should be in `.../other_repo/.git/config`